# What benefit does the brain have on computers in a human brain computer

Tags: computer-vs-human, human-computing

The concept of brain computer implants assumes that there's some net positive for either a machine or the brain when it comes to calculating or computing things. Usually there is a focus on what the computer can do for the human brain, but this takes the reverse. Essentially what exactly can the human brain do for a computer to make it run better or more efficiently.

On a conceptual level would a brain be able to expand the set of problems that a computer can solve (P-NP), help resolve things like deadlocks, thread starvation, short circuiting based on visual patterns (image processing), act as a shoe in to solve things like segfaults/access out of bounds errors, stop a program from completely crashing based on bad input or outputs, break out of infinite/bad loops, or counter things like adversarial inputs for networks by automatically filtering bad inputs out. Essentially working with the compiler/interpreter to reduce errors and improve processing time.

The question comes down to, what benefit does a human brain have for a computer when the two are combined.

One situation I can see is a brain greatly aiding a computer is in verifying NLP confidence values when running analysis on a sentence. Essentially a program is using something like the Viterbi algorithm to test how correct a certain sentence or conversation classification is. The human brain is better when it comes to language understanding because of things like cultural influence/grammar and will be able to aid in creating a better confidence of sentence classification. In this case the brain isn't doing any actual calculations, rather it is verifying a given solution. The major aftereffects are that it would help improve future classification accuracy by updating training sets or values. Without human verification a model could continually classify sentences wrong if it's never corrected.

All that said, I'm not sure if this is the place to ask the question. There doesn't seem to be a cognitive sciences stack exchange, and this doesn't really fit the bill for AI SE. If there is somewhere else better suited for this question, please let me know.

Comment: The human brain does that already. Millions of programmers use their brain everyday with that goal. Your perspective is generally not considered when talking about brain interfaces. Also note that computers can solve problems in NP — some not very efficiently.

Comment: @idmean True, but usually a programmer is doing their work before compile and runtime. But during run and compile time is there a place for the brain input is what I was wondering. Also true, computers can solve NP problems, but usually  it requires a backwards approach where you are verifying or know the answer already. NLP classification is a very rough example where human brain input is probably better for the verification approach than a computer/algorithm and can aid in processing the confidence of a classification or the weights of certain words/phrases.

Comment: Humans "help" computers offline by improving things such as compilers, static analyzers, theory of computing, algorithms, debugging and a lot more. As regards online help in real-time: absolutely nothing.